# url rewriting for magento pages

Tags: .htaccess, magento, url-rewriting

I am using multiple store website with domain www.example.com/index.php/storename/checkout/onepage/ and I want to change it to www.example.com/checkout-onepage/.

I have tried creating custom url in "URL Rewrite Management" in magento but it redirects to www.example.com/index.php/storename/checkout/onepage/ when i type www.example.com/checkout-onepage/ in the address bar.

Also i have tried using htaccess but this is also not working

```
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^checkout-onepage/(\d+)*$ ./storename/checkout/onepage/
```

I cannot set "Add Store Code to Urls" to 'No' in magento configuration (as it makes stop working the multi site admin). Is there any mistake I am making.

I have also tried in config.xml

```
 <global>
    <rewrite>
        <fancy_url> 
            <from><![CDATA[/checkout-onepage\/(.*)/]]></from>
            <to><![CDATA[checkout/onepage/index]]></to>
            <complete>1</complete>
        </fancy_url>
</rewrite>
```

But this also didn't results out correctly.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to change admin setting system -> configuration -> General -> web -> Url options ->  "Add Store Code to Urls" to No. if not work then refer this link [Magento remove store code for default store view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22039142/magento-remove-store-code-for-default-store-view) this link suggest how to set "Add Store Code to Urls" to No for store wise.

Check this link forcefully remove storecode from url this will be helpful to you. http://www.designhaven.co.uk/2013/10/force-removal-of-store-code-default-from-urls-in-magento/

Comment: but "Add Store Code to Urls" is not available store wise it is available globally.