# htaccess remove query string only for root

Tags: .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite, query-string, redirect

I want to remove a query string but only for the 6 cases below and never for any subfolders / other url's.

```
http://www.example.com/?___store=de&___from_store=de
http://www.example.com/?___store=de&___from_store=en
http://www.example.com/en/?___store=de&___from_store=en
http://www.example.com/en/?___store=de&___from_store=en
http://www.example.com/en/?___from_store=en
https//www.example.com/en/?___from_store=de
```

This is what I already got. It's working, but removes the query string from all url's, what I don't want.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} /?___store=de&___from_store=de
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} /?___from_store=de
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} /?___store=de&___from_store=en
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} /?___from_store=en
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [L,R=301]
```

I need this specific rewrite rule for a Magento shop. The store view code of the default store is removed by this extension: [Knectar/Magento-Store-Codes](https://github.com/Knectar/Magento-Store-Codes), see also this: [Magento remove store code for default store view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22039142/magento-remove-store-code-for-default-store-view).
As a result, the ___store query parameter is added to the url, but only on root.

My solution above does not work, because when it comes to products / categories the language switch is not working correctly anymore (and there is no need to remove the string, because it is stripped out by Magento itself).

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^___store=de&___from_store=(en|de)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(en/?)?$ $1? [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^___from_store=(en|de)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^en/?$ $0? [R=301,L,NC]
```